# Menu item doesn't appear after publishing google addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

My google sheets script is working well, but once it was published, the menu items are no longer there. So, instead of displaying the 'start' button in the addon (which works fine when it is run as a script) it only displays help for my addon. Does anyone have any ideas why this may be the case?

```
//Runs when the addon is installed 
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

//Creates menu entry in google ui when opened 

function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the menus doesn't show the add-on menu items and closing/open  the spreadsheet / force tab refresh solves the problem

Comment: I tried that and removing / downloading the addon, but its still doesn't work. I also looked at the console and didn't see any errors either.

Comment: If you are referring to the browser console, it will only show errors from client-side code. You should have to look to the Stackdriver logging/errors or to the Script Editor Execution Transcript. It's very likely that the problem is on another part of the add-on code. Is your add-on using global variables?

Comment: I'm not using any global variables, and my addon is working fine as a script when I'm running it locally. Are there any other ways of creating the addon menu that is better for a published addon versus a script?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
    .addToUi();
```

try

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var menu = ui.createAddonMenu();
menu
    .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
    .addToUi();
```

The above because changes made about how authorizations scope are being handled on add-ons could make that chained statements like the one used on the question code doesn't work as expected and because the examples on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus use more than one statement to create menus.

Comment: A weird fix that works was adding a second item! However, I've tried your approach, I'm just waiting for the publish to update it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Anant could you share what worked? Currently facing the same issue.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, it works in Test run for all modes, but post-install menu item does not show until I refresh the sheet. Have posted an issue  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153373886

Comment: I tried the solution suggested by @Rubén but it didn't work.  Only once I moved `function onInstall(e) { onOpen(e): }` to the very top of the .gs file.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you use the Spreadsheet instance globally (i.e. outside of functions):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // or other variable name
```

Locally it works but when the script is published as an add-on it generates problems.

The solution is to repeat that declaration in all functions where the instance is used or passed it fro other functions (and remove it from the global scope).

If you check the error in *Error reporting* in Google Cloud you may find this error detail:

> Exception: You do not have permission to perform that action. at
> [unknown function]